# Create and download file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have download csv file on button click. The file should be generated right before downloading. I tried to do it in the following way:

html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" @click="downloadCsv">Download CSV</a>
  <a v-if="fileObjectUrl !== null" ref="downloadCsv" :download="fileName" 
     :href="fileObjectUrl"
     :downloadUrl="downloadurl"></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
downloadCsv () {
  let csv = this.createCsv()
  let blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' })
  this.fileObjectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  this.$refs.downloadCsv.click()
},
```

But this is not working, since vue updates `fileObjectUrl` not immediately, so file is downloaded only when I click the button twice. Is there another way to create file and download it sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

From [Vue - Async Update Queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue):

> In case you haven’t noticed yet, Vue performs DOM updates
> asynchronously. Whenever a data change is observed, it will open a
> queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event
> loop. If the same watcher is triggered multiple times, it will be
> pushed into the queue only once. This buffered de-duplication is
> important in avoiding unnecessary calculations and DOM manipulations.
> Then, in the next event loop “tick”, Vue flushes the queue and
> performs the actual (already de-duped) work.

Vue hasn't updated the DOM by the time you `click()` so you need to have Vue wait a tick.  So, schedule the `clikc()` after the next tick using [`Vue.$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

So for you it would be:

```
this.$nextTick(function(){
    this.$refs.downloadCsv.click();
});
```